# How to fix --mangle-props error in uglify browserify?

Tags: node-modules, package.json, browserify, uglifyjs

I'm new to this, so I'm encountering an error. Basically I'm using this `browserify entry.js -d | uglifyjs -c -m --mangle-props --toplevel -o bundle.js`, where --mangle-props would be 'mangle' properties, the problem is that it is mangling browserify imports too.

**With --mangle-props**

```
1: [function(r, e, t) {
        e.exports = {name: 'Sky'}
    },{}],

2: [function(r, e, t) {
        var {} = r("./errors")
    },{ t: 1}] //error is Here
```

**No --mangle-props (normal)**

```
1: [function(r, e, t) {
        e.exports = {name: 'Sky'}
    },{}],

2: [function(r, e, t) {
        var {} = r("./errors")
    },{ "./errors": 1}]
```

If I change **t: 1** to "./errors": 1, it works. but I would have to do this on everything, after packing, does anyone have a solution? I don't know if it's correct to use this platform to ask this type of question.

Comment: I found the problem for anyone having the same problem. In `package.json`, mine was like this `browserify in.js -d | uglifyjs -c -m --mangle-props --toplevel -o out.js`. Maybe it's an error with uglify-js + browserify, I don't know but it asks you to add this `keep_quated`, thus `browserify in.js -d | uglifyjs -c -m --mangle-props keep_quoted --toplevel -o out.js`.